# AG Grid open in large text from context menu

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Using AG Grid is there a way to have a cell use the default `agTextCellEditor` editor but from the context menu be able to edit the cell with a `agLargeTextCellEditor`?

I haven't been able to figure out a way to set the columnDefs on the fly to accomplish this.

Trying to use the `startEditingCell` function with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wanna toggle between them.

Basically, you need to update column definitions. E.x.

```
action: () => {
  var columnDefs = gridOptions.api.getColumnDefs()
  columnDefs.forEach(function (colDef, index) {
    if (colDef.colId === 'athlete') {
      colDef.cellEditor = colDef.cellEditor == 'agTextCellEditor' ? 'agLargeTextCellEditor' : 'agTextCellEditor'
    }
  })
  gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs)
}
```

You may put an item in your context menu for this purpose and use the method above.

Here you are. I've got a plunker ready for you. Click on toggle to toggle between agTextCellEditor and agLargeTextCellEditor.

https://plnkr.co/edit/xz9WwmS9laL7saO5?preview

Comment: Not necessarily wanting to toggle. Mostly want to be able to open in the popup editor from the context menu without permanently changing cellEditor. But I think I can work with this solution and get it to work well enough for my use case. Thanks for your help! I appreciate the response.